# how to construct a class that requires a non-constant amount of heaps

Tags: java, class, constructor, queue

the program input in String[] args will look like this 123 0 0 where each rod of the hanoi tower is seperated by a space and each 1-digit integer represents a disk of that size.

How do I make a class of HanoiState that allows me to save the current state that is given as input, and make it so that moving any disk at the top of a rod, in this case it's "1", from one rod to the one adjacent to it is simple.

The command line prompt examples: $java hanoi 123 0 0 or $java hanoi 12 0 4 0

I was thinking of constructing n amount of priority queues for n amount of rods after parsing the input. However, the number of rods is not constant and I'm not sure how to code this.

Is it also possible to construct an array of priority queues? or a list of priority queues?

```
public static class HanoiState {
    public HanoiState(int rods){

    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 3) {
        return;
    }
    HanoiState a = new HanoiState(args.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rod is a stack of discs, so use the `Stack` class (`java.util.Stack`). Then, you can use the `push(item)` and `pop()` methods to put and take integers off of the top of each rod.

So each rod is a `Stack` of `Integers`. To take a disc off of rod `n`, call `rods[n].pop()` and to put a disc of size `i` onto rod `n`, call `rods[n].push(i)`.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class HanoiState {
    Stack<Integer>[] rods;

    public HanoiState(int numOfRods){
        this.rods = (Stack<Integer>[]) new Stack[numOfRods];
    }
}
```